# Exit eclipse and keep Java application running?

Tags: java, eclipse, exit, kill

How can I exit Eclipse without killing applications launched from within eclipse? I understand that applications launched in debug mode have a network link with Eclipse, but there should be no problem with applications launched in release mode. However, no matter how I end eclipse (even killing the process) kills the launched applications a couple of seconds later, regardless of important unsaved data in those programs.

Motivation? Can be any of: eclipse internal error which requests a restart, needing to free more memory (eclipse is 330MiB), accidental kill by process explorer.

Comment: Why do you need Eclipse to start the application? You said you don't want to start the app in debug mode so I'm confused why you'd want Eclipse to start a 'release mode' application? Are you debugging it?

Comment: There are ways to shave Eclipses mem. usage ( re: `eclipse is 330MiB` )

Comment: By 'release mode' I think he just means the normal run mode. But that application is linked to the eclipse console, so I'm not sure if there's any way to reconnect it elsewhere.

Comment: Eclipse is the parent process, what you are suggesting is you want to turn your apps into a bunch of zombies :).

Comment: @Gavin E: The reason is that I make research programs and I change code a lot until I'm satisfied (I need this agility). I'm thinking about making a .bat file to easily run them outside Eclispe. But this is way too much pain to do for EVERY program, and sometimes I do not know in advance that I'm going to run something for long periods. @Jyro117: Having a parent process has nothing to do with it. If I start a bunch of programs from the start menu, `Explorer` is the parent process. When I kill Explorer, the processes become orphans but stay alive.

Comment: Eclipse provides the standard inputs/outputs for any apps it launches. If you close Eclipse, those std IOs will be closed and many application will start to shutdown/throw exceptions in response to that. If you however launch the app in a way that the std IO points to something else, then Eclipse will not terminate them on exit. You might be able to use the "external tools" feature for this. Or maybe try uncheck the "Allocate console" option in the run configuration.

Comment: I think you are severely overestimating how hard it is to run compiled JAR files outside of Eclipse.  You might even be able to make an ANT task to run the JAR file outside of Eclipse....

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse uses it's own [emulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator) [sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29) to run the compiled source code.  Besides exporting your project to an executable `.jar` and running it outside of Eclipse, there is no way that I know of to close down Eclipse and have your program running, since you are shutting down Eclipse's emulator when you close Eclipse.

---

I don't think you know how an emulator works based on your comment.  Look at software such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).  When you run OS inside of it, you are still using the system resources of the OS on which you are running VirtualBox.

This is like Eclipse.  You need Java installed on your machine in order for Eclipse to work properly.  Eclipse still uses the Java on your main machine, but it puts it within it's own sandbox for the safety and security of the system, and emulates your program.  Look up how Eclipse runs it's programs if you don't believe me.

Also, some parts of Eclipse are written in Java, so you will also see some processes from that in the Process Explorer.

Comment: I never heard of release code running in in emulator. This is certainlty not the case in my Eclipse because when I inspect a running application with Process Explorer, I see the command line used to launch it and it contains nothing but classpath and main class parameters! Example: a program that's running right now was launched by Eclipse as `"D:\Program Files\java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\Dropbox\Eclipse\Cellular Automata\bin;D:\Dropbox\Eclipse\AllUtilities\bin" turmites.turmitesFast.TurmitesFastMain -Xmx4G`

Comment: Please see my edited post as to why your logic is somewhat off.

Comment: I think you're not getting the point. If a process is started as `javaw.exe`, it's just `javaw.exe`, not an emulator, otherwise I would see the process of the emulator instead. In fact, I ran two identical processes, one from eclipse and one from cmd, and the only difference I see in the process images is the presence of three named pipes in the eclipse-launched process.

Comment: You aren't listening to the answer I gave you, which is correct based on research and the up-votes I received.  If you aren't going to accept an answer given to you, don't ask the question.

Comment: @syb0rg, I'm interested in learning more about this eclipse sandbox mechanism but can't find any specific references. Can you share some links or keywords I can look at?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be going to be any way to do that, but really, none of the motivations you listed seems significative.

- Eclipse errors that require restarting are not usual.
- While you are developing you close Eclipse for freeing memory? You can shutdown the computer as well XD.
- Processes aren't killed accidentally. Don't kill what you don't know.
- And last, but most importat, an application launched from within Eclipse should run in a development environment, so there shouldn't never be "important unsaved data".

Comment: I hate it when people nitpick my well thought through reasons. Even if they might seem childish, I do actually have good reasons for them. The applications I run push the limits of my RAM to the point that Windows starts randomly killing processes (which sometimes is one of my launched programs). Restarting windows doesn't free up memory because there is no other program running that significantly consumes memory (my programs are the biggest, then follows Eclipse, then Firefox (which I usually close) and all other processes are just breadcrumbs.

Comment: Accidentally killing a process is rarer but happened to me when I hurriedly needed to close a misbehaving process. I open process explorer, type the first few letters of the process to highlight it and press Del, and then find out I made a typo or find out it already closed and I killed the next one alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

This exemplifies the danger of relying on tools, such as IDEs, to compile and run Java programs. Too many people (myself included) grow up learning Java the incorrect way: write the code, press the *Green Play Button*, and watch magic occur in the Console tab. Instead, Java programmers should first learn how to program using the command in order to understand the core basics of Java. This will help beginners understand concepts that a lot of veterans forget about; namely what a Classpath is. Also, this way you will know how to build and run your code on any environment in case you are having issues with an IDE.

Overall, an IDE is definitely helpful and I use one myself (Eclipse), but there always needs to be a command-line build/run process available as a fall-back option.

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: It is considerate that you mentioned this, but in fact, I DID start out coding in DOS, and I hated Java because each coding iteration was so slow (even compiling took very long). Later I used an IDE from Sun and I still hated Java. Only after I started using Eclipse, Java became my favorite language. And I only learned about classpaths from Eclipse from its superior organizing abilities. Still for the same reason (agility) I wanted a solution because I change code a lot between runs (I'm not talking about end-user programs but research programs)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Zom-B. Sounds to me like you would rather use a dynamic, non-compiled language like Ruby over a static, compiled language like Java.

Comment: I have over 11 years experience with Java and have no intention of learning another language. Besides I can't use non-compiled languages like Ruby because I need maximum performance. One simulation I'm running now takes 11 days at a speed of 200,000,000 read/writes per second to/from a 1GB byte array. Do you know of a dynamic language that can match this performance?